# Are SqlCipher open cursors a security concern?

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I'm using SqlCipher with content providers. Right now, when I want to lock the app I just clear out the cached password. However, the app can continue to work with any open cursors. This means that re-opening the app grants access to the sensitive data. I fix this issue on the surface by redirecting to a login screen if the app doesn't have passwords.

However, I'm concerned if there are any security issues with these open cursors or if I should just continue to block UI access and not worry? SqlCipher's docs say that it reads/writes encrypted pages on the fly, as opposed to decrypting the entire DB, this makes me think that open cursors are still secure.

The main concern here is that someone loses their phone and then a knowledgeable individual can use these open cursors to extract sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not looked at the details of the SQLCipher for Android implementation of cursors, but usually in Android cursors hold the whole result set in heap space, and in the case of SQLCipher, those would be decrypted by that point.

However, since those cursors are private to your process, there's no good way for anyone to get at them, courtesy of Linux/Android process isolation, except via your UI. If your UI does not allow anyone to get anywhere except via logging in again, you are fairly well protected. The catch is whether you are certain your UI does not have any unintentional code paths that would bypass the login (e.g., recent tasks list) and allow access at the data.

Comment: Regarding unintentional code paths. My first attempt was to write a custom Activity class that performed checks on all the possible entry points (onCreate, newIntent, etc) and then extend that secure activity class. This proved to be better in theory than in practice. Right now I just override each of the a fore mentioned entry points in each activity class. Unfortunately, this litters my app with repetitive code. Any thoughts on how to better accomplish this? I could kill the activity stack each time the app is locked, and only perform the check at the Main activity?

Comment: @user1178479: "I could kill the activity stack each time the app is locked, and only perform the check at the Main activity?" -- if locking the app is some explicit operation, you could use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as `Intent` flags to destroy all other activities when you bring up your lock activity via `startActivity()`.

Comment: that's good, but it would still be possible to circumvent that approach if your manifest has intent filters (such as "action.view") that would launch another activity, which was your point from the first post. I suppose the only way to really centralize control would be to create a gatekeeper activity that all intents go through in addition to clearing the activity stack upon lock. but that might be more work than it's worth and would pretty much render the manifest useless.